# are all active profiles are executed during maven build?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-profiles

when I run maven `help:active-profiles` on my project, I get the following

```
 nexus (source: external)
 - run-functional (source: project-Service:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT)
 - QA_LOCAL (source: project-parent:2.0.3-SNAPSHOT)
 - default (source: parent:pom)
```

Does this mean during `mvn build`, all these profiles are applied?
i.e when I run `mvn clean package`, all these profiles are active?

Answer (score 0):

From Maven's documentation:

> A profile can be triggered/activated in several ways:
>   * Explicitly
>   * Through Maven settings
>   * Based on environment variables
>   * OS settings
>   * Present or missing files

If you don't change any of these between running `mvn help:active-profiles` and your actual build, then all these profiles should be active.